# acNewRec doesn't work for combobox NotInList

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2016

I have ComboBox in Access form. It show list of items from db table. If item isn't found I want to create this record. So I use NotInList event:

```
Private Sub Combo9_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

When I'm trying to enter not existing item in ComboBox, it gives error:
[image]

But I created button and added the same code onClick event and it's working without problem.

What is wrong with NotInList? How I can use this event to add new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the error and whatever is entered.

```
Private Sub cboSelect_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

    Response = acDataErrContinue
    MsgBox "New entries are not permitted." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Please select an entry from the list or " & vbCrLf & _
        "move to a new record and add a new item below. ", , _
        "MsgBox Title"
    Me.cboSelect.Undo

End Sub
```

Comment: Then `DoCmd.GoToRecord`. I think you can do it in the same proc.

Comment: yes, Combo9.Undo did the job. I used also Combo9.Value = "". Otherwise I had unlimited cycle of NotInList event, which caused this error.

Comment: then include DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec to your code, to make answer complete.